# How to concat two columns in pandas,but by filling the Nan Value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

Ok, so i have two columns "Price 1" and "Price 2", some values in "Price 1" are Nan and some values in "Price 2" are Nan, but i want to concat them both.

My code and Output:

```
F3["Price 1"] = F3["Price 1"].fillna("0")
F3["Price 2"] = F3["Price 2"].fillna("0")

F3.index+=1

F3

    Price 1     Price 2
1   0        54.95
2   34.95    0
3   0        99.99
4   34.84    0
5   124.95   0
6   0        101.50
```

***So i want the final to be This Output Below:***

so the Data in Final Price will be filled From  "Price2" but only the 0 values will be filled in "Price 1"

```
 Final Price    
1   54.95       
2   34.95   
3   99.99       
4   34.84   
5   124.95  
6   101.50
```

Comment: If your data is in the **same pattern** then you can just add both prices i.e `F3['Final Price']=F3["Price 1"]+F3["Price 2"]`

Comment: `df['Final Price'] = df.sum(axis=1)`??

Comment: it can only concat str not float is the error i get

Comment: I assumed you did fillna before doing concatenating

Comment: yes i have done fill na as they Were "Nan" values before and i just made them to 0.

Answer (score 1):

It may be an extra step, but if you want to see the lists side by side, it's nice to make a data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

P1 = [np.nan, 34.95, np.nan, 34.84, 124.995, np.nan]
P2 = [54.95, np.nan, 99.99, np.nan, np.nan, 101.50]

df=pd.DataFrame({'Price 1':P1 , 'Price 2' :P2})

# the answer then is to use .fillna() with price 2.
df['Price 3'] = df['Price 2'].fillna(df['Price 1'])
df
```

Out:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
F3 = F3.fillna(0)
F3['Final price'] = F3['Price 1'].where(F3['Price 1'] != 0, F3['Price 2'])
```

alternatively without filling Nans:

```
F3['Final price'] = F3['Price 1'].where(~F3['Price 1'].isnull(), F3['Price 2'])
```

According to: [pd.Series.where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)

Comment: How is it different from the answer posted in the comment?

Comment: I was probably typing it while others were commenting. Apologies.

Comment: hi i tired this formula also, but the the final price column is the same as "Price 1" Column and nothing has changed . the 0 values have not been filled :(

Comment: Write this: F3['Price 1'] = F3['Price 1'].astype(float) and F3['Price 2'] = F3['Price 2'].astype(float) before the formula.

You have read the data as strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Price 1' : [0,34.95,None,34.84,124.95 ,None ],
                   'Price 2' : [54.95,None,54.95,None,None ,101.50 ]
                  })

df = df.fillna(0)

df['Final Price'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Price 2'] if row['Price 1'] == 0 else row['Price 1'],
                     axis=1)
```

Comment: Try to avoid apply if you can as it is slow.

Comment: hi i tired your formula but the the final price column is the same as "Price 1" Column and nothing has changed . the 0 values have not been filled :(

Comment: did you use fillna(0) before you ran the lambda line?

Answer (score -1):

thanks you for everyone for your help, but i finally solved it by first converting it into float value and then adding them together

```
F1["Price 1"] = F1["Price 1"].fillna("0").astype(float)
F1["Price 2"] = F1["Price 2"].fillna("0").astype(float)

F1['Final Price'] = F1.apply(lambda x: x['Price 1'] + x['Price 2'], axis=1)
```

Comment: You are fillina with a string not by a integer. `do fillna(0)` by introducing string you are changing your float column to object type